# Android: inflated elements not in material design

Tags: android, android-inflate

Okay, so that's the problem: 
When I try to create dynamically some checkboxes, they don't get the material theme even if I'm inflating them from an xml file.

EDIT:

java:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_volumi);


    FloatingActionButton add = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aggiunta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LinearLayout ll4;;// = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            ll4 = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.volume, null);



            ll.addView(ll4);

            //CheckBox cb;// = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            //cb = (CheckBox) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dynamic_check, null);
            //cb.setText("I'm dynamic!");

            //cb.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryColor));
            //cb.setId();



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aggiunto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Riccardo Ciovati now it works :D

Comment: From what class? What inflater are you using? Please post some code.

Comment: Try with `YourActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` when you inflate your views.

Comment: Thank you Riccardo, it worked ♥

grazie mille, e pensare che era una cosa banalissima :')

Answer (score 2):

If it's only about checkboxes, you can instantiate a tint-aware `CheckBox` with the [AppCompatCheckBox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatCheckBox.html) class.

There are other similar classes, like

- AppCompatEditText
- AppCompatRadioButton
- AppCompatRatingBar
- ...

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate them directly with a specific theme. Look in the docs there are several inflate methods